# Azure DevOps - Restrict merging to branches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, branching-and-merging

I'm looking to limit how merges are allowed to be done in Azure DevOps. I'm looking to replicate a setup that I had in [Atlassian Bitbutcket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwD0n.jpg).

So far I cannot see an easy or even a hard way to accomplish this in Azure DevOps. Right now the devs are merging directly into Master, and there are a number of internal devs and external contractors. I want to protect the main branch via hard limit policies. I know someone might suggest a solution to "just tell the devs to stop doing that", but unfortunately that never works. People are fallible, habits are hard to break, and "policies" go out the window when under a crunch or pressure to get something out quickly.

What I need to accomplish in DevOps:

- Master cannot be deleted or rewritten
- Nobody can push or merge directly to Master
- Master can only be changed by a PR, preferably only from the Dev branch
- Dev cannot be deleted or rewritten
- Nobody can push or merge directly to Dev
- Dev can only by change by a PR from an existing branch
- Tagged branches cannot be deleted or rewritten

If someone has a suggestion how to accomplish this I'm all ears, and very thankful.

Comment: In Git or TFvc? The Git has simple way for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a Branch Policy for the branches you want to do this on, this note is on that page

```
Branch Policies
Note: If any required policy is enabled, this branch cannot be deleted and changes must be made via pull request.
```

To get to Branch Policies -> in Project Settings choose Repositories then the particular Repository then Branch Policies are at the bottom - choose the branch.